# Add animation on progress bar android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to customise the progress bar in android (`@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar`) in such way that it changes the colour (for example it will be red for the first spin, then blue, then yellow etc.). Have read some things on internet and tried to use an animation-list, but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Android (API 21+) you can change the color programatically.

I would use a countdownTimer, It is probably not the best way but this it how i would do it :P :

```
//In the public class, make a variable which can simply be an int
int colorCode = 0; 


//then you put this code where your progress bar starts...

new CountdownTimer(3000,1000){
public void onTick(long millisUntilDone){

if(colorCode == 0){

colorCode = 1;

}else if(colorCode == 1){

colorCode = 2;

}else {

colorCode = 0;

}

if(colorCode == 0){
//To set it red, use:

//bar is a ProgressBar
bar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));

}else if(colorCode == 1){

//To set it blue, use:

//bar is a ProgressBar
bar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE));

}else {

To set it green, use:

//bar is a ProgressBar
bar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));

}

}


public void onFinish(){

//you don't have to set it to do anything...

}

}.start();
```

for API 16+ I think this would work better:

```
Drawable drawable = progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
drawable.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, customColorInt));
```

Just use this in every place where you would have used :

```
bar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
```

Comment: ok thank you, I could try doing such thing ... but will need to find a solution for lower aPIs as well (need to support 16+).. I thought that maybe there is an easier way to achieving directly in the xml files

Comment: I hope this helps :D